# Play framework deployment in jelastic cloud

Tags: java, playframework, playframework-1.x, jelastic

In my current project i'm using to Play! framework, now i've decided to publish my app in jelastic cloud. but every time i run `play jelastic:deploy` console prints the following message :

`~ Invalid command: jelastic:deploy`

P.S.
I.m using Play! version 1.2.4 , followed [this](http://blog.jelastic.com/2012/03/13/deploying-existing-play-applications-to-jelastic/) tutorial.
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The original tutorial on [JElastic](http://blog.jelastic.com/2012/02/13/play-in-the-cloud/) outlines more steps than the one you linked to.

In particular, you must install the plugin for Play! (Step 3.4 and following):

```
…\play-1.2.4>play install jelastic
…\play-1.2.4>play new jelasticapp –-with=jelastic
```

Comment: Yes, i've already followed this tutorial, and made your step, but still have this problem

Comment: There is an error in the syntax (it should be `--with=jelastic`. I've tried out the steps with this correction and it works.